# Python Bokeh Serve - DEBUG:bokeh.server.contexts:Scheduling 1 sessions to discard

Tags: python, debugging, server, bokeh

I am using bokeh server to stream data over interactive chart. The problem is :

- After a while, the log debug show me some DEBUG messages and the chart is stopping streaming some datas. The unique way is to refresh the webpage.

The error is :

```
DEBUG:bokeh.server.contexts:Scheduling 1 sessions to discard
DEBUG:bokeh.server.contexts:Discarding session 'dJR5oBmCninf9OspPA2v06SEyJCYVl1X6faig24O1oBt' last in use 21860.0 milliseconds ago
DEBUG:bokeh.document.document:Deleting 0 modules for <bokeh.document.document.Document object at 0x0000018572DB1788>
```

Thank you !